# I'm having trouble using an editable table in Shiny R and updating the data

Tags: shiny

I'm currently experiencing some difficulties working with an editable table in Shiny R. Specifically, I'm having trouble updating the table data and recalculating the sum of a column after an edit is made. Could you help me with this issue?

```
`library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(DT)

# Define a interface do aplicativo Shiny
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Título do aplicativo
  titlePanel("Edição de Tabelas em Arquivo .xlsx"),
  
  # Sidebar com o seletor de arquivo
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Selecione o arquivo .xlsx")
    ),
    
    # Corpo do aplicativo com a tabela editável
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
      textOutput("sum_col1")
    )
  )
)

# Define o servidor do aplicativo Shiny
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Lê o arquivo selecionado pelo usuário
  data1 <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    read_excel(input$file$datapath) %>%
      as.data.frame()
  })
  
  # Soma a coluna 1 da tabela
  sum_col1 <- reactive({
    sum(data1()[, 1], na.rm = TRUE)
  })
  
  # Define a tabela como uma variável reativa
  temp_data <- reactiveVal()
  
  # Renderiza a tabela editável
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(data1(), editable = TRUE)
  })
  
  # Atualiza a tabela quando um valor é editado
  observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
    info = input$table_cell_edit
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = info$value
    
    # Atualiza o valor na tabela
    temp_data<-data1()
    temp_data[i, j] <- DT::coerceValue(v, temp_data[i, j])
    data1(temp_data)
  })
  
  # Renderiza a soma da coluna 1
  output$sum_col1 <- renderText({
    paste("Soma da coluna 1:", sum_col1())
  })
}

# Executa o aplicativo Shiny
shinyApp(ui, server)
`
```

I'm having trouble updating the table data and recalculating the sum of a column after an edit is made.